# simple curve fitting in R

Tags: r, drc

I am trying to find a fit for my data. But so far had no luck.
Tried the logarithmic, different ones from the drc package .. but I am sure there must be a better one I just don't know the type.
On a different note - I would be grateful for advice on how to go about curve hunting in general.

```
library(drc)    
df<-structure(list(x = c(10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 
        20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 
        36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 
        52, 53, 54, 55), y = c(0.1066, -0.6204, -0.2028, 0.2621, 0.4083, 
        0.4497, 0.6343, 0.7762, 0.8809, 1.0029, 0.8089, 0.7845, 0.8009, 
        0.9319, 0.9414, 0.9505, 0.9323, 1.0321, 0.9381, 0.8975, 1.0929, 
        1.0236, 0.9589, 1.0644, 1.0411, 1.0763, 0.9679, 1.003, 1.142, 
        1.1049, 1.2868, 1.1569, 1.1952, 1.0802, 1.2125, 1.3765, 1.263, 
        1.2507, 1.2125, 1.2207, 1.2836, 1.3352, 1.1311, 1.2321, 1.4277, 
        1.1645), w = c(898, 20566, 3011, 1364, 1520, 2376, 1923, 1934, 
        1366, 1010, 380, 421, 283, 262, 227, 173, 118, 113, 95, 69, 123, 
        70, 80, 82, 68, 83, 76, 94, 101, 97, 115, 79, 98, 84, 92, 121, 
        97, 102, 93, 92, 101, 74, 124, 64, 52, 63)), row.names = c(NA, 
        -46L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), na.action = structure(c(`47` = 47L), class = "omit"))
    
    fit <- drm(data = df,y ~ x,fct=LL.4(), weights = w)
    plot(fit)
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1)** If we ignore the weights then y = a + b * x + c/x^2 seems to fit and is linear in the coefficients so is easy to fit.  This seems upward sloping so we started with a line but then we needed to dampen that so we added a reciprocal term.  A reciprocal quadratic worked slightly better than a plain reciprocal based on the residual sum of squares so we switched to that.

```
fm <- lm(y ~ x + I(1 / x^2), df)
coef(summary(fm))
##                  Estimate   Std. Error   t value     Pr(>|t|)
## (Intercept)  1.053856e+00  0.116960752  9.010341 1.849238e-11
## x            4.863077e-03  0.002718613  1.788808 8.069195e-02
## I(1/x^2)    -1.460443e+02 16.518887452 -8.841049 3.160306e-11
```

The coefficient of the x term is not significant at the 5% level -- the p value is 8% in the table above -- so we can remove it and it will fit nearly as well giving a model with only two parameters.  In the plot below the fm fit with 3 parameters is solid and the fm2 fit with 2 parameters is dashed.

```
fm2 <- lm(y ~ I(1 / x^2), df)

plot(y ~ x, df)
lines(fitted(fm) ~ x, df)
lines(fitted(fm2) ~ x, df, lty = 2)
```

[image: screenshot]

**2)** Another approach is to use two straight lines. This is still continuous but has one non-differentiable point at the point of transition.  The model has 4 parameters, the intercepts and slopes of each line. Below we do use the weights. It has the advantage of an obvious motivation based on the appearance of the data.  The break point at the intersection of the two lines may have significance as the transition point between the higher sloping initial growth and the lower sloping subsequent growth.

```
# starting values use lines fitted to 1st ten and last 10 points
fm_1 <- lm(y ~ x, df, subset = 1:10)
fm_2 <- lm(y ~ x, df, subset = seq(to = nrow(df), length = 10))
st <- list(a = coef(fm_1)[[1]], b = coef(fm_1)[[2]],
           c = coef(fm_2)[[1]], d = coef(fm_2)[[2]])

fm3 <- nls(y ~ pmin(a + b * x, c + d * x), df, start = st, weights = w)

# point of transition
X <- with(as.list(coef(fm3)), (a - c) / (d - b)); X
## [1] 16.38465
Y <- with(as.list(coef(fm3)), a + b * X); Y
## [1] 0.8262229

plot(y ~ x, df)
lines(fitted(fm3) ~ x, df)
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I agree. Polynomials are of course the easiest way if no interpretable parameters are needed.

Comment: Note that x^2 is in the denominator of the last term.

Comment: Ah, an inverse quadratic. Good idea.

Comment: Wow..! Thanks a lot your answer was not only useful, but inspirational.

Answer (score 2):

The basic idea is to understand how the selected function performs. Take a function you know (e.g. the logistic) and modify it. Or (even better) go to the literature and see which functions people use in your specific domain. Then create a user-defined model, play with it to understand the parameters, define good start values and then fit it.

Her a quick & dirty example of a user-defined function (with package growthrates). It can surely be made similarly with drc.

```r
library("growthrates")

grow_userdefined <- function (time, parms) {
  with(as.list(parms), {
    y <- (K * y0)/(y0 + (K - y0) * exp(-mumax * time)) + shift 
    return(as.matrix(data.frame(time = time, y = y)))
  })
}

fit <- fit_growthmodel(FUN=grow_userdefined, 
  p = c(y0 = -1, K = 1, mumax = 0.1, shift = 1), 
  time = df$x, y = df$y)

plot(fit)
summary(fit)
```

It can of course be made better. As we have no exponential start at the onset, one can for example start with a simple saturation function instead of a logistic, e.g. something Monod-like. As said, the preferred way is to use a function related to the application domain.

[image: modified logistic]